# Find vlan in RedHat Linux

Tags: rhel, vmware, tcpdump, vlan

I am using command `tcpdump -nvvvei eth0 -U| grep -i vlan` to find vlan in RedHat Linux. It is working for physical servers but not in virtual servers. Do we have any other way to find it?

Comment: what kind of virtual servers? Is the VLAN being added after the traffic leaves the RHEL system?

Comment: yes we have added vlan 2695 on eth2 as part of NAS-Avere migration and interface is configured.

Comment: Any update here please?

Comment: *how* did you add the vlan? VMWare? xen? kvm? inside the OS?

Comment: from VMware I have added.